# How to find a File path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, path, paperclip

I'm using the .foreach method from the [Ruby CSV library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html) and I need help in finding a path to a file within my rails application.

```
 CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
    # use row here...
  end
```

To upload CSV files I'm using the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) which has a method .url for the file location:

```
CSV.foreach(CsvUpload.last.csvfile.url) do |row|
   #more code
end

  CsvUpload Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `csv_uploads`.* FROM `csv_uploads` ORDER BY csv_uploads.id DESC LIMIT 1
No such file or directory - /system/csvfiles/17/original/uploadthis.csv?1305217588
```

The actual path of the file is:  `/Users/boris/projects/chaggregator/public/system/csvfiles/17/original/uploadthis.csv?1305217588`

**Is there a Rails method for getting the full path?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the "/Users/boris/projects/chaggregator/public" portion. Paperclip includes a `path` method to give this to you:

```
CSV.foreach(CsvUpload.last.csvfile.path) do |row|
  #more code
end
```

Comment: Obvious I should have caught that method.